# How to select and click dropdown menu item with selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm looking to sort a webpage from low price to high price by using the built-in product sort

I am able to successfully select the correct dropdown menu using xpath as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
         '//*[@id="react-views-container"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/button')))
```

This was intended only to be a test of sorts, as I am still relatively new to selenium. However, given this worked I cannot understand why the following does not:

```py
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
       EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
            '//*[@id="react-views-container"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[4]')))
```

This results in an error whereby the timeout is reached. It is not an issue of the timeout being too short. I have tried the div search for the given text, but that also did not work. Here is one example of the search I tried which was nearly copied from a similar question:

```py
Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Unit Price: Low First')]"))
```

Here is the HTML for the desired menu item:

```html
<div role="menuitem" tabindex="0" data-radium="true" style="background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247); padding: 8px 16px; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; color: white; white-space: nowrap; line-height: 20px; min-width: 260px; height: 36px; cursor: pointer;">
    <div data-radium="true" style="float: left; display: block; line-height: 24px;">Unit Price: Low First</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So I have just realized that the reason the xpath was not working is due to the path being too long. How can I shorten the path so that python can properly use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so that was a bit of a painful lesson in html and Selenium. Anyway, I figured it out by creating a list of all the menu items and then iterating through that list and clicking on the one I wanted. At the moment, I have this:

```
   menu_items=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@role="menuitem"]')
   for i in menu_items:
     if "Unit Price" in i.text:
       i.click()
       break
```

For some reason I cannot just do menu_items[4].click(), but I believe it is due to the elements list being a list of tuples or something, though I will have to check the documentation to verify this. I will update the answer afterwards.